# exploding string with multiple delimiter

Tags: php

i have a string like

```
$str = "1-a,2-b,3-c";
```

i want to convert it into a single array like this

```
$array = [
             1 => "a", 
             2 => "b", 
             3 => "c"
];
```

what i do is

```
$str = "1-a,2-b,3-c";
$array = [];
$strex = explode(",", $str);
foreach ($strex as $str2) {
    $alphanumeric = explode("-", $str2);
    $array[$alphanumeric[0]] = $alphanumeric[1];
}
```

can i do this in a better way?

Comment: This is clear and understandable code.

Comment: PD of [PHP Split Delimited String into Key/Value Pairs (Associative Array)](//stackoverflow.com/q/5290342) / [PHP - split String in Key/Value pairs](//stackoverflow.com/q/4923951) / [PHP Regex extract key-value comma separated](//stackoverflow.com/q/35495032)

Comment: Search sample: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+php+extract+comma+colon+key+value+pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens all the way down...

```
<?php

$str   = '1-a,2-b,3-c';
$token = '-,';

if($n = strtok($str, $token))
    $array[$n] = strtok($token);
while($n = strtok($token))
    $array[$n] = strtok($token);

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
  )
```

Or perhaps more terse without the first if...:

```
$array = [];
while($n = $array ? strtok($token) : strtok($str, $token))
    $array[$n] = strtok($token);
```

Comment: This was a very busy day for you -- four answers on one question.  But should this question have been closed as a duplicate instead?

Comment: @mickmackusa I didn't think it was aligned that well to the dupe.  And the question might not be seen as appropriate for SO.  I find the long drawn out answers with different solutions personally confusing, so prefer multi-answer approaches.  But I realise that's all a matter of taste.  On the face of it, this does read as pretty yucky but the benchmark adds interest.  Would suit the cookbook style.  Titles are the most difficult nut to crack here for people seeking solutions.  IMHO.

Comment: @mickmackusa there are regular famliar questions with familiar solutions on the site, but they don't quite align and many people just find it quicker to write a solution or approach.  It's quite difficult finding close matches.  I think SO needs an incubation area for questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `preg_match_all` for this:

```
<?php
    $str = "1-a,2-b,3-c";

    preg_match_all('/[0-9]/', $str, $keys);
    preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]/', $str, $values);

    $new = array_combine($keys[0], $values[0]);

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($new, 1) .'</pre>';
```

here we take your string, `explode()` it and then `preg_match_all` the `$value` using patterns:

- `/[0-9]/` -> numeric value
- `/[a-zA-Z]/` -> letter

then use `array_combine` to get it into one array

Thanks to u_mulder, can shorten this further:

```
<?php
    $str = "1-a,2-b,3-c";

    preg_match_all('/(\d+)\-([a-z]+)/', $str, $matches);
    $new = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($new, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('/(\d+)\-([a-z]+)/', $str, $matches);`

Comment: @u_mulder hot damn! I'd feel guilty editing my Q with updated code.. :'( I'll edit and give you a mention :p

Answer (score 3):

just a little [benchmark](https://phpmybenchmarks.kobject.net/Benchmarks/seeOne/100):

- 5000 iterations
- Debian stretch, php 7.3
- parsed string: "1-a,2-b,3-c,4-d,5-e,6-f,7-g,8-h,9-i"

[image: exploding string bench]

[edit] Updated with the last 2 proposals [/edit]

Comment: Looking at your linked benchmark, what's with the echo on the strtok?

Comment: Thank you @Progrock, I removed it.

Comment: Was optimistic that would shave a microsecond or two off.  Do you need to re-run your benchmarks?  (Interesting results BTW, thanks.)

Comment: Indeed, an `echo` doesn't change much (0.1 µs)
I restarted the test with and without echo

Comment: I've added another couple of solutions...  Don't feel obliged!

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_split with array_filter and array_combine,

```
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return $var & 1;
}
function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return !($var & 1);
}
$str = "1-a,2-b,3-c";
$temp = preg_split("/(-|,)/", $str); // spliting with - and , as said multiple delim
$result =array_combine(array_filter($temp, "even", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY), 
                       array_filter($temp, "odd",ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
print_r($result);
```

[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) — Filters elements of an array using a callback function

> **Note:-** **ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY** - pass key as the only argument to callback instead of the value

[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gp8pr)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do with `array_map()`,

```
<?php
$my_string = '1-a,2-b,3-c';
$my_array = array_map(function($val) {list($key,$value) = explode('-', $val); return [$key=>$value];}, explode(',', $my_string));
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($my_array)) as $k=>$v){
    $result[$k]=$v;
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/aYmOH

Answer (score 1):

Not a better way but one more example:

```
$str = "1-a,2-b,3-c";
$arr1 = explode(",", preg_replace("/\-([a-zA-Z]+)/", "", $str));
$arr2 = explode(",", preg_replace("/([0-9]+)\-/", "", $str));

print_r(array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory one-liner (your mileage may vary):

```
<?php
parse_str(str_replace([',', '-'], ['&', '='], '1-a,2-b,3-c'), $output);
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
  )
```

Comment: this or strok is faster in this case?

Comment: @JoeDoe, personally I wouldn't care about speed, I'd favour readability.

Answer (score 1):

This one explodes the string as the OP has on the comma, forming the pairs: (1-a) and (2-b) etc. and then explodes those pairs.  Finally array_column is used to create the associated array:

```
<?php

$str = '1-a,2-b,3-c';
$output =
array_column(
    array_map(
        function($str) { return explode('-', $str); }, 
        explode(',', $str)
    ),
    1,
    0
);
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'a',
  2 => 'b',
  3 => 'c',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one split on both the , and -, and then iterate through picking off every other pair ($k&1 is a check for an odd index):

```
<?php
$str = '1-a,2-b,3-c';

foreach(preg_split('/[,-]/', $str) as $k=>$v) {
    $k&1 && $output[$last] = $v;
    $last = $v;
}

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'a',
  2 => 'b',
  3 => 'c',
)
```

The preg_split array looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => 'a',
  2 => '2',
  3 => 'b',
  4 => '3',
  5 => 'c',
)
```