# How can I turn this string into a key value array?

Tags: php

I have a string like the one below, including the parenthesis:

```
("string" "value" "string" "value" "string" "value" ...)
```

The number of quoted parts are unknown with a minimum of one pair, I would like to turn this into an associative array, my desired result is:

```
array('string'=>$value,'string'=>$value, 'string'=>$value)
```

How could I do this? Preferably, I would like to use a built-in function or a one liner or create a custom function, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all?  Researched any string-manipulation or array-manipulation functions?

Comment: Perhaps you could adapt one of these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043328

Comment: Could string or value have a space in them?

Comment: @Progrock Yes, these values could have spaces, that is the reason they have quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use build-in functions :)

```
$str = '("string" "value" "string1" "value1" "string2" "value2")';

$str = preg_replace('~^\("|"\)$~', '', $str);
$ar = explode('" "', $str);
$ar = array_chunk($ar,2);
$ar = array_column($ar, 1, 0);
print_r($ar);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05d9062bf12daf70f9645d1e525c36356c2af947)

Comment: Your method worked great! You have introduced me to two new functions I hadn't used before, I read the documentation on these and it makes sense to me now, those functions are: array_chunk and array_column. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$str='("foo" "bar" "ying" "yang" "apple" "orange")';

$cols    = str_getcsv(trim($str, '()'), ' ');
$chunked = array_chunk($cols, 2);
$result  = array_column($chunked, 1, 0);

var_dump($cols, $chunked, $result);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "ying"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "yang"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "apple"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "orange"
  }
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "foo"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "bar"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "ying"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "yang"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "apple"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "orange"
    }
  }
  array(3) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["ying"]=>
    string(4) "yang"
    ["apple"]=>
    string(6) "orange"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to match the pattern of a pair of quoted strings, then fill the result array in a callback function using the two strings from the match.

```
preg_replace_callback('/"([^"]+)" "([^"]+)"/', function($match) use (&$result) {
    $result[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}, $str);
```